# React Router not redirecting to the right page, page redirected to is empty. No errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks

the following are not working:
The React Router "Link" is not working.

Let us say we are at the starting point: "localhost:3000/api/pages".

when I click the dropdown item, the link is: "localhost:3000/api/pages/api/pages/abc".

**It is supposed to be: "localhost:3000/api/pages/abc".**

I am getting no errors displayed in the console, however, it is not achieving the required behavior. It is not redirecting to the right page.

**When I go to the right page by entering it's URL, it's empty.

However, when I am not using any React Router routing during testing the page, the page was working fine, so I think the problem is with the routing**

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

class MyPage extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                     <Dropdown.Item as={Link} to="api/pages/abc">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} className="me-2"  /> Edit
                     </Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        );
    }
}

export default MyPage;
```

in another file:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="api/pages/abc" component={MyPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

What might be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to="api/pages/abc"` will link relative to the current path.
using an absolute path should help: `to="/api/pages/abc"`

Answer (score 0):

add "exact" before "path" in your code. and using absolute path

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route excat path="/api/pages/abc" component={MyPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add "/" to make the path into `/api/pages/abc`.

And import the file you want to route.

```
import MyPage from './the/path/of/the/file';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/api/pages/abc" component={MyPage} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```